# Knockout sorting alphabetically

Tags: knockout.js

I have read other stack overflow's about this knockout sorting issue but can't seem to solve my own problem.

I would like for the newly added items to automatically sort alphabetically when submitted. Heres my code...

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        <hr />
<h3>Add New Item</h3>
<label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: newItemName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
        <br />
<label>Unit Price: </label>
        <input type="number" min="0.25" step="0.25" data-bind="value: newItemPrice, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
        <br />
<label>Quantity: </label>
        <input type="number" min="1" step="1" data-bind="value: newItemQuantity, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
        <br />
<button data-bind="click: addNewItem, enable: addNewItemEnabled">Add Item</button>
<hr />
<h3>Items in Cart</h3>
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsInCart">
        <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td>$<span data-bind="text: price"></span></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: quantity"/></td>
                <!--<td>$<span data-bind="value: totalPrice"></span></td>-->
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">X</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: sortItems">Sort</button>

<h3> Combined Cost $<span data-bind="text: combinedCost()"></span></h3>
```

And here is my knockout code...

```
var viewModel = {
    newItemName: ko.observable(),
    newItemPrice: ko.observable(0.25),
    newItemQuantity: ko.observable(1),


    addNewItem: function () {
        //this creates the new item
        var newItem = {
            name: ko.observable(this.newItemName()),
            price: ko.observable(this.newItemPrice()),
            quantity: ko.observable(this.newItemQuantity())
        };
        //these boom-a-rang to the DOM
        this.itemsInCart.push(newItem);
        this.newItemName("");
        this.newItemPrice(0);
        this.newItemQuantity(0);

    },
    //Remove from array
    removeItem: function(item) {
        viewModel.itemsInCart.remove(item)
    },
    //the cart storage
    itemsInCart: ko.observableArray([])

};

viewModel.sortedItems = ko.computed(function(){
    return itemsInCart().sort(function (a,b){
        return a.newItemName() == b.newItemName() ? 0: (a.newItemName() < b.newItemName() ? -1 : 1);
    });
}, viewModel);

//whenever any events fire including keyups, downs,..etc this part updates
viewModel.addNewItemEnabled = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var name = this.newItemName(),
        price = this.newItemPrice(),
        quantity = this.newItemQuantity();
    return name && name.length;
}, viewModel);


viewModel.combinedCost = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= viewModel.itemsInCart().length - 1; i++)
            total += parseFloat(viewModel.itemsInCart()[i].price() * viewModel.itemsInCart()[i].quantity());
            console.log("test", total);
        return total;
    }, viewModel);

viewModel.sortList = ko.computed(function() {

}, viewModel);


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't using observableArrays ? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html have an inbuilt sort method

Comment: Is this not it? //the cart storage
    itemsInCart: ko.observableArray([])

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in all the ko.computed functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

**[EDITED]**

```js
addNewItem: function () {
    //this creates the new item
    var newItem = {
        name: ko.observable(this.newItemName()),
        price: ko.observable(this.newItemPrice()),
        quantity: ko.observable(this.newItemQuantity())
    };
    //these boom-a-rang to the DOM
    this.itemsInCart.push(newItem);
    this.newItemName("");
    this.newItemPrice(0);
    this.newItemQuantity(0);
    
  this.ItemsInCart.sort(function(a,b){
     var a1 = a.name().toLowerCase();
     var b1 = b.name().toLowerCase();
     return a1.localeCompare(b1);
  });



}
```

Comment: Where would this go exaclty?